# Cannot unscrew stuck shower arm

Tags: plumbing, shower, pipe

I’m replacing my old shower arm but it stuck and won’t move not even a bit.
The picture is my old adjustable shower arm remnants(female) attach to the pipe(male) coming out of the wall.

I tried heating then unscrew, WD-40, lime a way and pipe wrench but nothing worked so far.
WD-40 was so hard to spray in the thread also...i don’t think it was going into thread that much.

Before calling plumber, is there anything I could do?
[image]

Thank you,

Comment: Welcome! What kind and how big is your wrench? (How long is the handle?) You're rotating it the correct direction? (counter-clockwise)

Comment: Would be tempted to cut the head off to leave the large nut, get a socket on it and impact or breaker bar it off

Comment: As a side note, that looks to be a 60s or 70s era fiberglass shower surround. It's likely be be effected by any sort of thread loosening chemicals you might want to apply, so use caution when spraying things on it.

Answer (score 3):

You need more leverage. To do that use a pipe wrench with a cheater bar attached so the handle is longer. Slip a 1 inch (or comparable) diameter pipe length onto the handle. This will greatly increase the torque you exert. Counterclockwise direction is loose.

Apply force slowly and in increments. Most likely there's a sweated copper fitting behind the shower arm and it can break if over torqued.

A more passive way to remove it would be with a hacksaw. Make a diagonal cut on top of the squared shoulder of the shower arm. Cut until you see the 1/2 inch nipple that it's threaded to. Make the cut from its base to the end of the square shoulder. It will spin right off when completed.